# Closing effortless questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I think we/the mods should be stricter with question that show no effort.

I don't think we should provide solutions to questions that just state what they want to do but show nothing which they tried.

Answer (score 8):

No.

> *+ "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"*

If someone obviously spent time for research and/or clear question vote up.

> *- "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*

For me this is an "AND + OR" condition. For some questions there is no "measurable" research effort, but it can be clear and useful - and visa verse.

I would like the downvote function to be used more frequently.